# Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, objectmapper

Converting my code from `swift` 3 to 4 and getting the error
Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]'

On line

```
attributedString.addAttributes(boldAttributes, range: NSRange(location: index, length: linkType.keyPhrase.count))
```

With bold attribute highlighted

Here is the full code

```
    private func addLink(_ linkType: AttributedURLType, attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString) {

        let indeces = attributedString.string.indices(of: linkType.keyPhrase)
        let boldAttributes: [String : Any] = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: LocalConstants.termsBoldFont,
            NSAttributedStringKey.link.rawValue: linkType.url
        ]

        for index in indeces {
            attributedString.addAttributes(boldAttributes, range: NSRange(location: index, length: linkType.keyPhrase.count))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode 9: Cannot convert value of type '\[String : Any\]' to expected argument type '\[NSAttributedStringKey : Any\]?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46359772/xcode-9-cannot-convert-value-of-type-string-any-to-expected-argument-type)

Comment: Remove rawValue

Answer (score 3):

Well, you initiated your `boldAttributes` variable with a [String : Any], and your error tells you this is not the expected type of variable. So initiating the variable with `[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]` and removing .rawValue should solve your problem.

Your attributes dictionary will be like this:

```
let boldAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    .font: LocalConstants.termsBoldFont,
    .link: linkType.url
]
```